# How do I wrap a macro definition in an environment?

Tags: macros, environments

I'm creating a style file, and want to store the body text of the abstract environment so that I can put it on my custom titlepage. I could have required that my users enter the abstract as

```
\customabstract{Abstract text goes here}`
```

which I would have implemented as something like

```
\newcommand{\customabstract}[1]{\gdef\abstracttext{#1}}
```

However, I would prefer that the user is able to use environment notation,

```
\begin{customabstract}Abstract text goes here\end{customabstract}
```

To do this, I thought I could define something like

```
\newenvironment{customabstract}{\gdef\abstracttext\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

But this definition makes `\abstracttext` expand to `\bgroup`, which is not what I wanted. I tried to solve the problem by `\expandafter`,

```
\newenvironment{customabstract}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\abstracttext\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

but this results in a runaway error.

Is there any way to acheive what I want? Answers that helps me understand the inner workings of TeX (instead of just referring to a custom package) are preferred.

Comment: See the environ package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do

```
\gdef\abstracttext\bgroup...\egroup
```

because the braces around the replacement text of a macro must be explicit. Besides, TeX never does expansion when absorbing the replacement text of a macro, so `\end{customabstract}` would not be interpreted and, even if implicit delimiters were allowed, you'd get an incomplete definition anyhow.

The usual solutions for this are as follows:

1. making a box that's saved and then delivered at the appropriate spot; this is how the AMS classes do, for instance;
2. using the `environ` package, which is more flexible, because it allows formatting the text at point of use, rather than at point of call.

Here's an implementation of the second idea.

```
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{customabstract}{\global\let\abstracttext\BODY}
```

Explanation. With `environ`, the environment's contents is temporarily saved as the replacement text of `\BODY`.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer, which explains why my approach was not working. The environ package seems nice, I did not know about it before.