# Wrap tikz matrix/tikzcd inside vcenter

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, tikz-cd, xparse

How could I create an environment that wraps a `tikzcd` (basically a tikz matrix) inside `\vcenter{...}` while keeping the syntax intact?

**What I tried**: According to [How do I wrap a macro definition in an environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273980/how-do-i-wrap-a-macro-definition-in-an-environment) I need to use `environ` or `NewDocumentComment{+b}` (I prefer the later since it seems to be "native" now). But then the environment turns into a macro and I have troubles with `&` (see [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices/611535#611535)).

**/!\ Note that I don't want to change `&` into `\&`!** So I tried to adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611535/116348 to environments, but not sure how to do.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,positioning}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{vtikzcd}{O{}+b}{
  \ensuremath{%
    \vcenter{%
      \hbox{
        \begin{tikzcd}[#1]
          #2
        \end{tikzcd}
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
% Ok
\begin{tikzcd}
  A & B\\
  C & D
\end{tikzcd}

% Fails:
\begin{vtikzcd}
  A & B\\
  C & D
\end{vtikzcd}

\end{document}
```

I tried to define:

```
\newenvironment{vtikzcd}{
  \begingroup% To avoid ampersand issues https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611535/116348
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{tmpZX}{O{}+b}{%
    \endgroup%
    \ensuremath{%
      \vcenter{%
        \hbox{%
          \begin{tikzcd}[##1]%
            ##2%
          \end{tikzcd}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }{}%
  \catcode`&=13
  \begin{tmpZX}%
}{\end{tmpZX}}
```

but it does not compile.

**EDIT**
Instead of using `\vcenter`, I managed to center the diagram appropriately (including one line diagrams) by editing instead the style, using something like:

```
baseline={([yshift=-.27em]current bounding box.center)},1-row diagram/.style={%
      /tikz/baseline={([yshift=-.27em]current bounding box.center)}%
    }]
```

I'm not sure exactly which value I should pick for yshift tought. That said, I'm still interested by this question in case I want later to wrap my environment with any command.

Comment: Wrapping `tikz-cd` is in general a bad idea because of all the `\catcode` things (not only `&`). I'd say the `baseline` approach is more natural and flexible (in the sense that you may replace `.27em` by something else, like `.5ex`).

Comment: One more thing, check out `axis_height` in the `tikz-cd` manual.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks a lot for `axis_height`, `baseline={([yshift=-axis_height]current bounding box.center)}` (same for `1-row diagram`) works great. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618054/fake-vcenter-in-tikz-using-baseline/618057#618057.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `&` is used in Ti*k*Z matrices (which `tikzcd` environments is a particular case of), its category code is changed to active (13). But this is not possible when the code is passed as the argument to another command.

So your

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{vtikzcd}{O{}+b}{% <--- this is necessary
  \ensuremath{% <--- this is not necessary
    \vcenter{% <--- this is not necessary
      \hbox{% <--- this is necessary
        \begin{tikzcd}[#1]
          #2
        \end{tikzcd}% <--- this is necessary
      }% <--- this is not necessary
    }% <--- this is not necessary
  }% <--- this is necessary
}
{}
```

doesn't work (I added the necessary `%` and `{}` that you missed), because the environment's content is grabbed as the argument to a command.

So you should not use the `b` argument type, if you don't want to add `ampersand replacement=\&` and type in `\&` inside `vtikzcd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newsavebox{\vtikzcdbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{vtikzcd}{O{}}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\vtikzcdbox}
    $\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup
    \begin{tikzcd}[#1]
}{%
  \end{tikzcd}%
  \egroup\egroup$
  \end{lrbox}
  \usebox{\vtikzcdbox}%
}

\begin{document}
% no vcenter
X\begin{tikzcd}
  A & B\\
  C & D
\end{tikzcd}X

% vcenter
X\begin{vtikzcd}
  A & B\\
  C & D
\end{vtikzcd}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to pursue the `b` way, you can replace all `&` with `\&`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{vtikzcd}{O{}+b}
 {
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand~replacement=\&,#1]
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { & } { \& }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \end{tikzcd}
  }}}
 }
 {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% no vcenter
X\begin{tikzcd}
  A & B\\
  C & D
\end{tikzcd}X

% vcenter
X\begin{vtikzcd}
  A & B\\
  C & D
\end{vtikzcd}X

\end{document}
```

Don't overuse the `b` argument type. It's a possibility, not the best one in all cases.

Comment: Thanks you so much! Btw, why do you need the `lrbox`? I tried without and it seems to work fairly well. Can I say that  a general recipe to wrap macro around environment is to replace `{` by `\bgroup`?

Comment: @tobiasBora That removes the need for `\ensuremath`.