# Fake vcenter in tikz using baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

In order to fake `\vcenter` in tikz, I've been using `baseline={([yshift=-.25em]current bounding box.center)}`. It seems to work fairly well, but not sure if it's strictly equivalent (like I'm not sure if the `.25` is exact, nor if it will work for any font size...). I tried `\show\vcenter` (see logs), but it does not give the definition (or it's a single macro definition).

Is it the correct way to proceed?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent ABC $\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.27em]current bounding box.center)}]%
    \node[inner sep=5mm,fill=green] at (0,0){n};%
  \end{tikzpicture}}}$
$\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.25em]current bounding box.center)}]
  \node[inner sep=5mm,fill=green] at (0,0){n};
\end{tikzpicture}= 42$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\show\vcenter` doesn't provide useful information since `\vcenter` is a TeX primitive. In centres a box vertically on the math axis, whose height is controlled by `\fontdimen22` of the `\fam=2` font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newdimen\axisheight
\setbox0=\hbox{$a$\global\axisheight=\fontdimen22\textfont2}%

$
\hbox{X}           % a normal X on the baseline
 -                 % minus sign to show the math axis
\vcenter{\hbox{X}} % an X centred on the math axis
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-\axisheight]current bounding box.center)}]%
    \node[inner sep=1mm,fill=green] at (0,0){X};
\end{tikzpicture}
$
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I know close to nothing about `tikz` so I guess this is the alignment you are trying to achieve.)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Note that `tikzcd` also defines it similarly https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/blob/c1eb4c96291b48a4a7f9f348b2e22473dd48de3d/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex#L294 and can be used inside a tikzcd using `baseline={([yshift=-axis_height]current bounding box.center)}`