# How to avoid broken vertical alignment in tabularray cells when some of the cells include images or pictures like tikz pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, vertical, tabularray

In the following table, I have included text in the first cell and a tikz image (a square) in the second cell. Although I have configured the first cell to be middle vertically aligned, it fails to be as such. If I hadn't included the tikz picture in the second cell, or I had just text, then the first cell would be perfectly middle aligned. Please note that tikz image is much smaller and it fits comfortably in a much bigger cell. Also note that neither the contents of the second cell is properly vertically aligned. Is there a problem to include tikz pictures or just images in tabularray tables? Is there any incompatibility, or is there a **setting or command, preferably but not necessarily, inside the tabularray package** to fix it? I tried **\raisebox** command but sometimes works, sometimes does not.

MWE: with tikz picture

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{tabularray}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},rows={4cm,m},vlines,hlines}  
        This is a $2\times2$ square & \tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2); \\  
    \end{tblr}  
\end{document}
```

output1:

[image]

MWE: without tikz picture

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{tabularray}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},rows={4cm,m},vlines,hlines}  
        This is a $2\times2$ square & just text in place of tikz square \\  
    \end{tblr}  
\end{document}
```

output2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens whenever a line in the second column has unusual height, and a `tikzpicture` usually qualifies, see the first example below.

You can shift the baseline to the picture center (second example) or even shift it a bit less, using a slight modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618057/4427 (third example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$x$}}% to be sure the math fonts are computed
\tikzset{baseshift/.style={yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},rows={4cm,m},vlines,hlines}
This is a $2\times2$ square &
\rule{1pt}{50pt}just text in place of tikz square: see?
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},rows={4cm,m},vlines,hlines}
This is a $2\times2$ square &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},rows={4cm,m},vlines,hlines}
This is a $2\times2$ square &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([baseshift]current bounding box.center)}]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see much better now! IMO the best result is achieved in example 3, so I follow it. As I understand is better to include in my preamble in all documents the line \AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$x$}} when using math fonts, to be accurately calculated? Shall I have to change in tikz style definition the fontdimen and textfont dimensions when using bigger or smaller size fonts?

Comment: @MiltosP. Math font sizes are computed and globally when a formula is typeset for the first time after a size change. You can possibly find a way to ensure that `\check@mathfonts` is executed at each `tikzpicture`, if you're afraid that the computation hasn't been done.

Comment: What about when not using tikz so we don't have the tikz style available and we use \includegraphics command of graphicx package to insert an image in a cell? Can we do something similar in this case to change the position of baseline?

Comment: @MiltosP. With `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can do `\includegraphics[valign=c,<other options>]{filename}`

Comment: @egreg congratulations on crossing the exalted 1million mark WOW