# How to align table with tikz picture side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, align

I am trying to align a table of data along side a tikz picture made only of the axis and grid used to draw by hand the data.

However, the grid in tikz picture is not aligned with the middle of the table. And I don't know why.

Here is my latex code :

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}   
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{m{3.5cm}m{11cm}}
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!10!white}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{gray!15!white}
        y $\left(\text{kg.m}^{-3}\right)$ & x $\left( \varnothing \right)$\\
        \midrule
        798 & 0,0 \\
        810 & 0,1 \\
        831 & 0,2 \\
        852 & 0,3 \\
        873 & 0,4 \\
        894 & 0,5\\
        916 & 0,6\\
        937 & 0,7\\
        958 & 0,8\\
        979 & 0,9\\
        1000 & 1,0\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (10,10);
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
\end{tabular}
```

And I end up with something like this :
[image: resultat]

The table and grid are not aligned... which would be smoother.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: [How to avoid broken vertical alignment in tabularray cells when some of the cells include images or pictures like tikz pictures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652619/how-to-avoid-broken-vertical-alignment-in-tabularray-cells-when-some-of-the-cell). It may help you.

Comment: As Miltos P. recommended, the answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652619/how-to-avoid-broken-vertical-alignment-in-tabularray-cells-when-some-of-the-cell)

Comment: Alignment is done by adjusting the baseline.  If yous add `\hfill\llap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}` at the end of the line, it will show where the baseline is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}   
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{3.5cm}m{11cm}}
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!10!white}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{gray!15!white}
    $y\cdot\left(kg\cdot m^{-3}\right)$& $x (\O)$\\ % <--I changed this line to work
        \midrule
        798 & 0,0 \\
        810 & 0,1 \\
        831 & 0,2 \\
        852 & 0,3 \\
        873 & 0,4 \\
        894 & 0,5\\
        916 & 0,6\\
        937 & 0,7\\
        958 & 0,8\\
        979 & 0,9\\
        1000 & 1,0\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    &\raisebox{15.5mm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw[step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (10,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

output:[image]